# Can one download Anaconda (Linux) on Raspberry Pi directly from Anaconda's website?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, anaconda

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Raspbian OS, and it already has Python installed, but I've always used Anaconda with the Spyder IDE.

I'm pretty new to Linux so I am wondering if I can go directly to Anaconda's website and download the Linux distribution to install it?

I want to make sure so I don't mess up anything. How would this affect the current Python installation on the Pi?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I go directly to Anaconda's website and download the Linux distribution to install it?

Yes and no. You can download the proper files from Continuum (they make Anaconda/Miniconda), but you need to make certain the distribution your download matches your CPU architecture. In the case of the Raspberry Pi 3B+, this is an ARM chip (which isn't the same type of chip found in a regular desktop PC). Therefore, you need an ARM distribution of Miniconda.

You should have a look at this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371772/how-to-install-anaconda-on-raspberry-pi-3-model-b) if you want step-by-step instructions on how to get the proper version of Miniconda for the Raspberry Pi 3B+ and install it. Currently, the second answer appears to have the most up-to-date "How-To".

> How would this affect the current Python installation on the Pi?

To the best of my knowledge, if you followed the instructions above, Miniconda would be installed along side Python 2 and Python 3 (already installed on the Pi) and its default environment would (likely) be set as your default Python installation. Anaconda/Miniconda is designed to be self-contained and thus shouldn't affect other versions of Python on the Pi.

> I've always used Anaconda with the Spyder IDE.

As a small side note, Spyder can be installed separately from Anaconda with `pip` (e.g. `pip install spyder` or `python -m pip install spyder`). I wouldn't recommend this on Linux (or your Pi), but anecdotally, it was a breeze to install without Anaconda on Windows 7 (`Python 3.6.8` with `Spyder 3.3.5`).

Comment: hi, Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh is a pretty old almost 5 years old version. but the official website doesn't provide the latest version for arm architecture. do you have any idea about it?